# If we remove the diagonal from $X\times X$, is it necessarily disconnected?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

If $X$ is a compact, connected Hausdorff space, we know that the diagonal $\Delta_X=\{(x,x)\in X\times X\}$ is closed in $X\times X$ by Hausdorffness. But is $X\times X\setminus\Delta_X$ disconnected in general? I know that, if $X$ has a total order $<$ such that the induced order topology is contained in the original topology (i.e. it is coarser), then we can write
$$X\times X\setminus\Delta_X=\{(x,y)\in X\times X:x<y\}\sqcup\{(x,y)\in X\times X:x>y\}$$
Also, if $\Delta_X$ is a [zero-set](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroSet.html), then we also have the disconnectedness of $X\times X\setminus\Delta_X$ since, if $\Delta_X=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$, then we have the disjoint open sets $f^{-1}[(-\infty,0)],f^{-1}[(0,+\infty)]$. But we don't have that $\Delta_X$ is a zero-set in general as $X$ [may not be first countable](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/?q=Connected%2B%24T_2%24%2BCompact%2B%7EFirst+Countable) and $\Delta_X$ being $G_\delta$ implies $X$ first countable [for compact Hausdorff spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3261640/if-x-hausdorff-compact-with-g-delta-diagonal-then-x-has-a-countable-b).

Comment: There is a trivial example: $X = \emptyset$

Comment: I
 haven't thought through all the details, but I think if you take an infinite $X$ under the cofinite topology, you will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $X=\mathbb R^2$.

The diagonal in $X \times X = \mathbb R^4$ consists of all $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb R^4$ such that $a=c$ and $b=d$, which defines a 2-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^4$.

With a bit of linear algebra one can apply an invertible linear transformation to convert this into the subspace defined by the equations $a=0$ and $b=0$, the complement of which is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb R^2 - \{(0,0\}) \times \mathbb R^2$, which is path connected.

Comment: Note that $\Delta_X$ is a zero-set in this case, since it's the set of zeroes of the function $(a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2$. Contra the OP, there is no contradiction because zero-sets don't have to be zero-sets of surjective maps to $\mathbb{R}$ (and this one only lands on non-negative).

Comment: Right, although perhaps the OP was thinking of some kind of regular $\mathbb R$-valued zero set.

Comment: Any closed set of a $T_6$ space is a zero set. Where OP made a mistake is that we can have one of pre-images $f^{-1}[(-\infty, 0)]$ or $f^{-1}[(0, \infty)]$ to be empty.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, there is a famous theorem due to Eilenberg,
see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371274) or [here](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/13258), Theorem 3.

Definition: A topological space $(X, \tau)$ is *weakly orderable*, if there is a linear order on $X$, such that $\tau$ is finer than the order topology generated by this linear order. 
$(X, \tau)$ is *orderable*, if there is a linear order on $X$, such that $\tau$ equals the order topology generated by this linear order.

(Note that in the above referenced paper of Kok, weakly orderable spaces are called orderable and in Eilenberg's paper ordered.)

Theorem (Eilenberg).
Let $X$ be connected, $T_1$ and $|X| \ge 2$.

1. X is weakly orderable, iff $X^2 \setminus \Delta_X$ is not connected.
2. $X$ is orderable, iff $X^2 \setminus \Delta_X$ is not connected and $X$ is locally connected.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be $\Bbb{R}$ with the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) (any infinite set would do: I'm just using $\Bbb{R}$ so I can use geometrical language).  The closed subsets of $X$ are either empty, finite or equal to the whole real line $\Bbb{R}$. For each point $(x, y)$ in a closed subset $C$ of $X \times X$, either $(x', y) \in C$ for all $x'$ or for only finitely many $x'$ and either $(x, y') \in C$ for all $y'$ or for only finitely many $y'$. It follows that, if the projection of $C$ onto the $x$-axis is infinite, then $C$ contains an entire horizontal line and if the projection onto the $y$-axis its infinite, then $C$ contains an entire vertical line. If $X \times X \setminus \Delta_X = C \cup D$, where $C$ $D$ are closed in the subspace topology on $X \times X \setminus \Delta_X$, then the projections of both $C$ and $D$ onto the coordinate axes are surjective and this implies that $C$ and $D$ cannot be disjoint.